# CQ link or url component

Tags: hyperlink, adobe, aem

Is there any cq component that renders a link for external website url

> anchor tag with href to an external url

Creating a component where user enter "name", "link", "background-image".

Output a DIV with bacground-image with text on top of it. When user clicks on the text, it should open new window and go to the link (external company site url/ NOT CQ) entered.

Thank you,
Sri

Comment: Provide the detail of the usecase

Answer (score 1):

AEM OOB provide several generic components, your usecase is very specific to your project need so feel free to create a new component for same. I feel this is low complex requirement.